# Installing my Python program as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, service

I am trying to figure out how to release a Python program I wrote and have it be able to be run as a service in Ubuntu. Much like Nginx, where you can call `sudo service nginx stop` and `sudo service nginx restart`.

Is there any way to allow people to install my program like this? Perhaps making an `install.py` file that does it for them? I want people to be able to clone my Github repository for this project and walk through a few steps to install the program.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705564/python-script-as-linux-service-daemon

Answer (score 0):

You could have it run as a daemon. Doing this would allow you to run the stop and restart commands you mentioned.

For example:

`python program.py stop`

`python program.py restart`

Install the [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) package in Ubuntu.

`sudo apt-get install python-daemon`

```
from daemon import Daemon
class YourDaemon(Daemon):
        def run(self):
            # Your code here
```

An alternative is to use the [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) process control system.